# SwiftUI ZStack reversed positioning order of views using alignmentGuide()

Tags: layout, swiftui

I am trying to display a custom layout using ZStack of a table with a column titles and some rows, but I get a reversed layout to the order I specify in the body.  Here is the code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Test: View {

    var columns : [String] = ["Column 1","Column 2"]

    var cells : [[String]] = [
        ["(1,1)","(1,2)"],
        ["(2,1)","(2,2)"],
        ["(3,1)","(3,2)"],
    ]

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            ForEach(0..<self.columns.count, id: \.self) { column in
                self.viewForCell(self.columns[column], row: 0, column: column)
            }
            ForEach(0..<self.cells.count, id: \.self) { row in
                ForEach(0..<self.cells[row].count, id: \.self ) { column in
                    self.viewForCell(self.cells[row][column], row: 1+row, column: column)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func viewForCell(_ string: String, row: Int, column: Int) -> some View {
        Text(string)
            .alignmentGuide(.leading, computeValue: { _ in CGFloat(96 * column) })
            .alignmentGuide(.top, computeValue: { _ in CGFloat(24 * row) })
    }
}

struct Test_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Test()
    }
}
```

And here is a screenshot of what I get: [image]

What I want is:

```
"Column 1" "Column 2"
"(1,1)"    "(1,2)"
"(2,1)"    "(2,2)"
"(3,1)"    "(3,2)"
```

It appears as if the horizontal and vertical alignments are flipped.

Answer (score 0):

```
import SwiftUI

struct Test: View {

    var columns : [String] = ["Column 1","Column 2"]

    var cells : [[String]] = [
        ["(1,1)","(1,2)"],
        ["(2,1)","(2,2)"],
        ["(3,1)","(3,2)"],
    ]

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            ForEach(0..<self.columns.count, id: \.self) { column in
                self.viewForCell(self.columns[column], row: 0, column: column)
            }
            ForEach(0..<self.cells.count, id: \.self) { row in
                ForEach(0..<self.cells[row].count, id: \.self ) { column in
                    self.viewForCell(self.cells[row][column], row: 1+row, column: column)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func viewForCell(_ string: String, row: Int, column: Int) -> some View {
        Text(string)
            .alignmentGuide(.leading, computeValue: { _ in CGFloat(96 * ( self.columns.count - column )  ) })
            .alignmentGuide(.top, computeValue: { _ in CGFloat(24 * ( self.cells.count - row ) )})
    }
}

struct Test_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Test()
    }
}
```

@andrewz the problem was in the value of the leading and the top of the alignmentGuide of the cell
the above code will work as you expect :)

Comment: It works, but I don't understand why we have to calculate the x/y offsets from the bottom-right  corner .. I assumed the coordinate space originates in the top-left, isn't that the case?  Can you provide a link to any official documentation about this?

Comment: @andrewz yes the coordinate space originates in the top-left like always, but here we are talking about the behaviour of the alignmentGuide, i did not find any official documentation but this link will explain you more what i am talking about
https://swiftui-lab.com/alignment-guides/